# OCaml re2 on multi-line string

Tags: ocaml, re2

I just try to use [re2](https://github.com/janestreet/re2) to replace a regex in a file, the test was passed for a simple string.

```
# module Re2 = Re2.Std.Re2;;
# let re = Re2.create_exn "<key>Tags.*<\\/array>" ;;
# let orig =  "abc <key>Tags</key><array><string>OCaml</string></array> end";;
# Re2.replace_exn ~f:(fun _ -> "<key>Tags</key><array/>") re orig;;
- : string = "abc <key>Tags</key><array/> end"
```

However, when I put the contents into file as `ss.xml`:

```
<key>Starred</key>
<false/>
<key>Tags</key>
<array>
    <string>Think</string>
    <string>Performance Test</string>
    <string>Racket</string>
    <string>OCaml</string>
</array>
<key>Time Zone</key>
<string>Asia/Shanghai</string>
```

The OCaml source code:

```
open Core.Std
open Async.Std

module Re2 = Re2.Std.Re2

let trans_reg (input: string) : string =
  let re = Re2.create_exn "<key>Tags.*<\\/array>" in
  let target = "<key>Tags</key><array/>" in
  Re2.replace_exn ~f:(fun _ -> target) re input

let handle_file (filename: string) =
  let%bind text = Reader.file_contents filename in
  Writer.save (filename ^ ".xml") ~contents:(trans_reg text)

let () =
  Command.(run (async ~summary:"" Spec.empty (fun _ -> handle_file "ss.xml")))
```

Nothing's gonna change in my new file `ss.xml.xml`.

I was wondering:

1. How to regex match in this case.
2. When shall we use the parameter of [replace](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/re2/Re2_internal_intf/S.modt/#/replace.val)`Match.t` in `~f:(Match.t -> string)`? ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re2 has an option `dot_nl` which controls whether `.` will match `\n`.  By default, `dot_nl` is false.  You can set it true either using the flag syntax `(?s)<key>Tag.*<\\/array>` as documented [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) or in OCaml by calling

```
Re2.create ~options:[ `Dot_nl true ]
```

I do not believe the `m` flag is relevant here because `m` controls the interpretation of `^` and `$`. Your pattern does not use `^` or `$`.

Also, obligatory warning: [You cannot parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I just want to modify the data of DayOne journal, the xml format is simple, regex works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Re2 matches your regular expression line-by-line by default, that's why your expression never matches.

[The documention](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) mentions a `m` flag for multiline matching. I don't know if JaneStreet's binding for re2 lets you set such a flag, but this is definitely what you're looking for here.

I'll keep a eye out for and I'll update my answer shoud I find something useful.